# POST method for RestHeart API

Tags: mongodb, restheart

We know that RESTHEART API can provide data using GET method. But if the list of paramaters grows then GET Rest call will hit the limit.
Please confirm if we can use POST calls to fetch data via rest heart.

something like
GET /test/coll?filter={'title':{ << 1000s.. params >>}}

Here I am just illustrating the long list of parameters using << 1000 params >>

Regards,
Abhinav

Comment: Try a Google search: https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/RH/pages/9207882/Reference+sheet

Answer (score 0):

RESTHeart strictly follows the HTTP protocol and the RESTful paradigm:

According to the RFC 261

[POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.5)

> The POST method is used to request that the origin server accept the
> entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the resource
> identified by the Request-URI in the Request-Line.

We have discussed between the community about allowing to GET data with a POST but rejected it.

Said that, your need is clear but it can be addressed with a RESTHeart custom [Application Logic Handler.](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/IoCw)

Comment: thank you. I will take a look at Application Logic Handler. Much appreciated!!

Comment: so after reading the document . what I understand is, I need to override handleRequest method and check  METHOD.POST . Is that right?